# Testing Share.share in React Native with Detox

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

I'm trying to write an e2e test using Detox for a flow where a user shares a deeplink to a certain screen in the app. I want to be able to capture the share link generated when a user clicks the 'share' button (which on a real device would open the native share popup), then navigate to that link using `device.openUrl()`. It should look something like this:

```
await element(by.id('test-id-of-share-button')).tap();
const sharedUrl = obtainTheUrlPassedToTheSharePopupBySomeMagicalVoodooWay();
await device.openURL({ url: sharedUrl });
await expect(element(by.id('test-id-of-element-on-target-screen'))).toBeVisible();
```

Thing is, I don't know how to do this nicely. I can probably [Mock](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md) the [Share](https://reactnative.dev/docs/share) module, but then I'll somehow have to pass the data from the mock function to the test process. I can probably do this by running a simple http server in the test and calling that server from the mock function, but I think that there's got to be a better way to do that.

Would appreciate any insight.